# Scrapy multiple next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape every next page. I've found a way to do it with scrapy shell but I don't know if my spider will iterate through every page or just the next one; I'm not too sure how to implement that.

```
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
each_link = '.' +  alphabet 
each_url =  ["https://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter={0}".format(i) for i in each_link]
#sub_page_of_url = [[str(url)+"&show{0}".format(i) for i in range(50, 2000, 50)] for url in each_url] #start/stop/steps
#full_url =  each_url + sub_page_of_url

class AnimeScraper_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Anime"

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in each_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback= self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
     next_page_url = response.xpath(
        "//div[@class='bgColor1']//a[text()='Next']/@href").extract_first()

     for href in response.css('#content > div.normal_header.clearfix.pt16 > div > div > span > a:nth-child(1)') :
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_anime)
    yield Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_anime(self, response):
        for tr_sel in response.css('div.js-categories-seasonal tr ~ tr'):
            return {
            "title" :  tr_sel.css('a[id] strong::text').extract_first().strip(),
            "synopsis" : tr_sel.css("div.pt4::text").extract_first(),
            "type_" : tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            "episodes" : tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first().strip(), 
            "rating" : tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(5)::text').extract_first().strip()
            }
```

Comment: Try to create `counter=0` and do increment `counter += 50` in `while True` loop on each iteration. The condition for `break` should de `if response.status == 404: break`

Comment: Could you provide an example ? i don't see how to do this assumed that i need to click on page 3 to got the href of page 4

Comment: You should add the counter as additional  parameter to your URL. For instance if `url = "https://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=a"`, then URL for each page should be `url + "&show={}".format(counter)`. And on each iteration counter will be `0` for page 1, `50` for page 2, `100` for 3 etc...

Comment: Counter = 0
while True :
    Counter +=50
    for href in response.css('#content > div.normal_header.clearfix.pt16 > div > div > span > a') :
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
    url + "&show={}".format(Counter)
    if response.status == 404 :
        break , is there something missing ? it take a while to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're trying something too complicated, it should be as simple as:

1. Start from the main page
2. Identify all the pages that start with a particular letter
3. For each of these pages, take all the next links and repeat

It looks something like that:

```
import string

import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class AnimeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "Anime"
    start_urls = ['https://myanimelist.net/anime.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        xp = "//div[@id='horiznav_nav']//li/a/@href"
        return (Request(url, callback=self.parse_anime_list_page) for url in response.xpath(xp).extract())

    def parse_anime_list_page(self, response):
        for tr_sel in response.css('div.js-categories-seasonal tr ~ tr'):
            yield {
                "title":  tr_sel.css('a[id] strong::text').extract_first().strip(),
                "synopsis": tr_sel.css("div.pt4::text").extract_first(),
                "type_": tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first().strip(),
                "episodes": tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first().strip(), 
                "rating": tr_sel.css('td:nth-child(5)::text').extract_first().strip(),
            }

        next_urls = response.xpath("//div[@class='spaceit']//a/@href").extract()
        for next_url in next_urls:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(next_url), callback=self.parse_anime_list_page)
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks ! But i would like to understand how there's one point that i don't understand it's "next_urls" how did you find @class="spaceit" i didn't see that in html code.

Comment: If you go to https://myanimelist.net/anime.php?letter=A and scroll to the bottom of the page, you will see the next page links like: [1] 2 3 ... 16. If you inspect the HTML at this area, you will see that the div with 'spaceit' class is enclosing these links.